# On NSRunLoop, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsrunloop

When i

```
    Logger *logger = [Logger new];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    __unused NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
            initWithRequest:request delegate:logger startImmediately:YES];
```

... nothing happens. Delegate methods are not called until i

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]run];
```

I would have thought that `startImmediately:YES` would do exactly that.

Comment: is this code running in a separate thread or the main thread or?

Comment: are you in a command line app or a gui app?

Comment: Command line app. I am following the book examples on this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

async callbacks require an NSRunLoop. See:

[Cocoa: NSURLConnection not attempting an HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267163/cocoa-nsurlconnection-not-attempting-an-http-request)

command line apps don't have an NSRunLoop by default - gui apps do.

From the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

initWithRequest:delegate:
Returns an initialized URL connection and begins to load the data for the URL request.

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate
```

> ... for the connection to work correctly, the calling thread’s run
>   loop must be operating in the default run loop mode. See
>   scheduleInRunLoop:forMode: to change the run loop and mode.

Comment: Bryan - do you mean to say that GUI apps automatically get the `NSRunLoop` whereas command line apps need to have it declared explicitly?

Comment: Thank you sir. Very helpful indeed.

Comment: GUI apps have an NSApplication which has a run loop.  Here's another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630854/can-i-make-an-asynchronous-nsurl-connection-in-a-basic-foundation-objective-c

Comment: The thread in a non-GUI program _has_ a run loop, it's just not running. Part of the `NSApplication` start-up process is to run the loop.