# Getting updated availableFonts from NSFontManager while activating fonts in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts

I posted a similar question about using Python to do the same thing, but I rewrote this little program using objective-c and Cocoa and got the same result. Here's the other Stack Overflow question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980677/polling-nsfontmanager-sharedfontmanager-in-python The purpose of submitting the question again is to reach out to the Objective-C and Cocoa experts, and who knows, maybe the answer is different. So here it goes.

I'm trying to write a small little terminal program that will get a list of fonts that OS X sees as active, and report how many are active, over a period of time. For example, while the program is running, if I have 120 fonts active, it should report 120 fonts active, then if I activate 10 more fonts  while the program is running, it should report 130 fonts active. The issue I'm running into is that it doesn't seem like the sharedFontManager instance is updating in my for loop. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        for(int y=0; y < 5; y++){

        NSArray *sysFonts;
        NSFontManager *manager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
        sysFonts = [manager availableFonts];

        NSLog(@"Number of active fonts: %lu", [sysFonts count]);
        sleep(5);
        sysFonts = nil;
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

So if you'd like to test this you'll need a couple hundred fonts to activate and deactivate. Start with your fonts deactivated (select the fonts, right-click, select "Disable Fonts"). Run the program. When you see the terminal say "Number of active fonts: " pop back into Font Book, right-click on the selected fonts and click "Enable Fonts" (feel free to change sleep(5) to something longer or shorter. The number is in seconds), it will repeat the loop 5 times (again, you can change this number too).

The results I keep ending up with are the same number of activated fonts, but I know this is inaccurate because if you have activated a large number of fonts (somewhere around 500 fonts), you have enough time to re-run the program and see that the number has decreased or increased from the previous time you ran the program, depending on if you activated or deactivate the large number of fonts. In other words, I know font activation is occurring, and I expect to see the number of fonts changing.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a really good question. I can definitely reproduce the problem here, and I don't know why the font manager doesn't update. I was able to get it to update by calling the private method `‑_reactToFontSetChange` just before calling `[manager availableFonts]` but that's not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it @RobKeniger! If you happen to find a way to do what I'm trying to do, let me know. You mentioned that you were able to get it to update by calling the private method `_reactToFontSetChange` and I trust that it's not ideal, but if it's the only way, would you mind letting me know how I'd call the private method? I'm a bit fresh to programming, but I catch on pretty quick. :)

Comment: The simplest way is to just call `[manager performSelector:@selector(_reactToFontSetChange)]`.

Answer (score 3):

You may run a `NSRunLoop` and use the `NSFontSetChangedNotification` mechanism to update the `sharedFontManager` instance!

```
/*

Getting updated availableFonts from NSFontManager while activating fonts in Cocoa
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995017/getting-updated-availablefonts-from-nsfontmanager-while-activating-fonts-in-coco

references:
- NSFontAttributeExplorer
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSFontAttributeExplorer/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003960
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NSFontAttributeExplorer/NSFontAttributeExplorer.zip
- NSFontManager Class Reference
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336693/on-nsrunloop-clarification-needed
- /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSFont.h


compile with:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -x objective-c -framework AppKit -o getfonts getfonts.m

usage:

./getfonts

( ./getfonts > font.log ) &
pid=$!
# kill -HUP $pid


# play around with "Disable selected fonts" & "Enable selected fonts" button
open -a 'Font Book'  

*/


#import <AppKit/AppKit.h> 


// create a counter to avoid createFontList() being called twice for a single font adding / removing event
// Is there any alternative?
static int counter = 0;  


@interface FontLogger : NSObject
{
   NSFontManager *mysharedFontManager;
}
- (id)init;
-(void)createFontList;
@end


@implementation FontLogger

- (id)init
{
   if ((self = [super init])) 
   {
      mysharedFontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
      [self createFontList];
   }
   return self;
}


-(void) setNSFontSetChangedNotification
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fontSetChanged:) name: NSFontSetChangedNotification object: nil];
}

-(void)createFontList
{

   counter = counter + 1;

   if (counter == 1)
   {
      NSString *name = NULL;
      NSArray *fontarray = [mysharedFontManager availableFonts];
      NSEnumerator *nameEnum = [fontarray objectEnumerator];

      int i = 0;
      while ( (name = [nameEnum nextObject]) )
      {
         //NSLog(@"font: %@", name);
         printf("%s\n", [name UTF8String]);
         i = i + 1;
      }
      printf("Number of available fonts: %i\n\n", i);
      fflush(stdout); 

   }else {
      counter = 0;
   }

}

- (void)fontSetChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"NSFontSetChangedNotification"])
   {
      [self createFontList];
      //NSLog (@"Successfully received notification!");
   }

}

@end


int main (void)
{

   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   FontLogger *getAvailableFonts = [[[FontLogger alloc] init] autorelease];

   [getAvailableFonts setNSFontSetChangedNotification];

   BOOL terminated = NO;

   while(!terminated && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

   [pool release];

   return 0;

}
```